# How to calculate the number of night and day hours between two dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

The night time is from 22:00 to 07:00 and may vary (maybe moment.js, but there is no concrete implementation in it). Any tips, links to other resources will help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want separate numbers for both day and night

Comment: You mentioned `moment.js` a good alternative could be `date-fns` see here: https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started you might find something in there.

Comment: It sounds like you might actually be more interested in solar calculations?  They are very dependent on latitude and longitude.  Try a library like [SunCalc](https://github.com/mourner/suncalc).

Answer (score 0):

I worked in a task very similar. The idea behind is to identify that you have two periods, lets say, your "night time" and the period you want to compare. if instead of periods you think of these intervals as sets, the intersection between these two sets is the night time.

So, for example, lets say your interval is `2019-09-30 13:00:00` to `2019-10-01 08:00:00` (using datetime, of course). So, your night time is `2019-09-30 22:00:00` to `2019-10-01 07:00:00`, the intersection is `2019-09-30 22:00:00` to `2019-10-01 07:00:00`, that actually are the night period, and the rest is the daytime. Once you have the intervals, you can easily calculate the amount of time in the range.

You can use [Moment Range](https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range) to help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this.

```
var FirstDate = Date.now();

DoSomethingForATime();

var SecondDate = Date.now();

var result = SecondDate - FirstDate;
```

or

```
var firstDate = new Date("see Date documentation to go furter in custom date");

var secondDate = new Date(customDate);

var milisecondsBetweenDates = secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime();
```